# Difficulty setting up web server on azure with port 80 (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, azure

Using ubuntu on azure, I can create a web server on port 3000 but not on port 80. I've created endpoints for both in the azure portal.  What's the difference and why can't I create one on port 80?  Thanks!

Comment: More information is needed on this. Hint: to bind ports below 1024, root privilege is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run your web server on any port above 1024 on the Ubuntu VM, and then set that as the Private Port and 80 as the Public Port in the Endpoints settings in the Management portal.